# Re-Deploying a Custom Magento Store

Tags: admin, migration

I have developed a niche Magento store that only uses some of Magento's features. It also has a custom back end that I have developed over time.

So here is the issue, I now need to deploy another store identically the same as the store I have developed.

I want to be able to do this fast without installing a new version of Magento on my server and having to disable all of the settings that are disabled on my first site and apply all of the changes to the back-end once again.

I basically need a copy of my admin and the settings within it. The front end theme will be different so I'm not bothered about that being the same.

Can anyone think of a solution for this?

Comment: Clone the site (files & db), then switch themes from cloned site.